# JS Array.find if undefined element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to merge two arrays:

```
productsAll = parserArrayFull.map((item) => {

        return {
            ...item,
            ...firestoreArrayFull.find((y) => y.productSKU === item.SELLER_SKU),
        };
    });
```

Everything works OK if in "firestoreArrayFull" there is  "productSKU" with the same value like item.SELLER_SKU. But if not there is error 
"Cannot read property 'productSKU' of undefined"
How to make condition for this situation? I would like to keep "item" only in the case of error.
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have some null values in `firestoreArrayFull` array.

Try put `y &&` before you make a comparison to make sure `y` isn't `null` or `undefined`.

```js
productsAll = parserArrayFull.map((item) => {
    return {
        ...item,
        ...firestoreArrayFull.find((y) => y && y.productSKU === item.SELLER_SKU),
    };
});
```

#### Update

- If not found, adds `productSKU` property equals to `item.SELLER_SKU`.

```js
productsAll = parserArrayFull.map((item) => {
    return {
        ...item,
        ...(firestoreArrayFull.find((y) => y && y.productSKU === item.SELLER_SKU) || { productSKU: item.SELLER_SKU }),
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It excluded without error now. But i need to add key productSKU which is the same like item.SELLER_SKU to returned array if not found.Regards